# Copy files from pwd to another directory using Python

Tags: python, file, directory, copy, shutil

I'd like to copy all files in my present working directory to another location.

I have tried variations of the below:

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile('/*','/my/other/directory/location')
```

This gives the error: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/*'`

I am thinking about using `os.system` and the `cp` command.

Has anyone got any better ideas?

Comment: What environment? Is it local copying ?

Comment: Are you referring to    cp -r [source] [target]

Comment: on linux (but SSH via MinGW) with `cp -f -R -L $local/* my location`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use shutil. Is there a problem with that ?

Personally I tend to use:

```
shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None)
```

as it takes subdirs

update------

To get the current working directory use

```
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: I think my error may be in how I reference 'all files in the present directory' with `/*`... I'll amend question

Comment: if you use copytree you don't have to think about the files, it simply copies all.

Comment: I have tried it, I think my problem is that I don't know what to write for `src` to get everything in the present directory...

Comment: got it src is `../mydirname`

Comment: great,:-) I like os.getcwd() better though